# jQuery, PHP, MySQL Login Retaining page query

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-mobile, authentication

I have a very simple login script that works for the needs of this site. The problem is that some of these pages are accessed via an outside link, and include a query string. The question is, how best to produce the login page and retain the query string. I tested the method below, but, after logging in, I end up with a blank page.

The idea behind this file is to include it the very top of protected pages. The $Page variable is set just before the include.

Login goes to top of page, checks authorization and, if valid, loads the underlying page. Otherwise, presents the login  screen and goes back to the top of the page on submission.

Adding a query string to a form in this way may not be standard, but it does work, from my experience, in normal HTML. A more sensible way might be to parse PHP's SERVER[QUERY_STRING], and loop it into hidden inputs. I haven't tried that yet, but I thought I would put this up, as someone might have a better idea altogether.

```
    <? session_start();
include('funclogin.inc');
if($_SESSION['LoggedIn']){ LogOut(); }
else
{
    if($_POST[Submit])
    {
        if(empty($_POST[User]) || empty($_POST[Pass]))
        {
            $LoginResult = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            // Checks that Username is in database and password is correct
            $LoginResult = ConfirmUser($_POST['User'], $_POST['Pass']);
            if($LoginResult == 1)
            {
                $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!$_SESSION['LoggedIn'])
   {
   ?>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
           <head>
               <title>
                 My Title
               </title>
               <? include('include/MobileHead.inc'); ?>
           </head>
           <body>
               <div data-role="page" id="LoginPage">
                   <? include('include/MobileHeader.inc'); ?>
                   <div data-role="content">
                       <form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="post" action="<?PHP echo($Page.'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); ?>" data-ajax="false">
                           <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="User">Username:</label>
                               <input type="text" id="User" name="User" maxlength="12" autofocus required />
                           </div>
                           <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="Pass">Password:</label><input type="password" id="Pass" name="Pass" maxlength="15" required /></div>
                           <input type="hidden" name="K" value="<?PHP echo($_REQUEST['K']); ?>" />
                           <input type="hidden" name="M" value="<?PHP echo($_REQUEST['M']); ?>" />
                           <div data-role="fieldcontain"><input data-theme="b" type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Enter" /></div>
                       </form>
                   </div><!-- /content -->
                   <? include('include/MobileFoot.inc'); ?>
               </div><!-- page -->
           </body>
       </html>
   <?PHP
   }
}
?>
```

EDIT:
The solution I came up with follows:
On the page in which I want to require a login,

```
if(!$LoggedIn)
{
    $Page = "http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.php";
    header('Location: login.php?Page='.$Page.'&'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
```

In login.php
Set the query string, which now includes the page, in the Action of the form:

```
<form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="post" action="<?PHP echo($_SERVER[PHP_SELF].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); ?>" data-ajax="false">
```

So, on successful login, I do this

```
$LoginResult = ConfirmUser($_POST['User'], $_POST['Pass']);
if($LoginResult == 1)
{
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true;
    $QueryString = "";
    if(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
    {
        $Str = explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        $Count = count($Str);
        for($i=0;$i<$Count;$i++)
        {
            $Var = explode('=',$Str[$i]);
            if($Var[0] == "Page")
              {
                 $Page = $Var[1];
              }
              else
              {
                 $kv[] = $Str[$i];
              }
           }
           $QueryString = join("&", $kv);
        }
        Redirect($Page.'?'.$QueryString);
     }
```

Redirect is just some JavaScript i put into a PHP function for convenience:

```
function Redirect($n)
{
    die("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location='$n';</script>");
}
```

Comment: Why is the first thing you do, when someone is logged in and goes to a page, to log them out?

Comment: The user is sent to the script only if they are not logged in (thus the "LogOut" is ignored) or if they press the "Log Out" button, which, of course, is only visible when they are logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is in a few steps:

- Someone accesses your logged-only page: `/member?mydata=x`
- You check the session, and if they're not logged in, you redirect them to the login page, keeping the query string: `/login?mydata=x`
- On the login page, you either modify the form action to include the query string or you set the query string in the session
- If logging in is successful, you either read the query string from the check page, or read it from the session and redirect user accordingly.

You can modify this to work if you want to preserve the full original path (`/member?mydata=x`) and redirect there instead of the standard post-login page. But the idea is the same: see what they asked for, retain in through the login process and redirect accordingly.

Comment: Yeah - seems the main problem is trying to do this all on one page, which jQuery doesn't seem to like much. I tried parsing the query string and putting it into hidden variables, but it still went nowhere. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Didn't know you want it on one page. In that case, you should use a login popup when needed, and make it do an AJAX call to check credentials and update session. And if AJAX returns success, just refresh the page and then it should pick up the session login parameter set in the AJAX call and load the page normally without the login popup.

Comment: That did the trick, although I had to do some maneuvering. I put the query string in the login form Action, with "Page" as the first var in the string, then parsed it out into 2 variables - Page and QueryString. I added this in an edit.

Comment: Yeah, whatever works, there are always many options. Sometimes you can even use a hidden input field to transfer values. Btw. you should probably do url_encode on the full url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Some pieces of your code produce PHP warnings/notices, for example: `$_POST[Submit]` should be `$_POST['Submit']`.

If it are a few parameters that are fixed (do not change), it is indeed a good option to put them in your form (as hidden field) and send them to your login process page. Aren't the query parameters send to the next page because they are in the form action?